# Curio Mount Everest

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

I am new to house plants and brought my Curio a couple of weeks ago. I put it in a room that has a lot of light but not direct sun light. The bottom of one of the stems turned a grey, purple colour I then moved it to another room to a windowsill where it gets a lot more light. I have also watered it weekly so the soil is moist but not sitting in water. Would appreciate some advice. Thanks in advance. [image]